# FUNCTION database.coluna does not exist

Tags: php

Nesse select a baixo esta dando este erro   (FUNCTION base.coordenadas does not exist)

```
    $sql ="select  AsText(coordenadas) from cerca_gps where coordenadas(
    GeomFromText('POLYGON((-22.970981 -43.217496 ))'),coordenadas )";
```

Como posso corrigir esse erro, oque estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: O que você pretende com este trecho? `where coordenadas(` Que função "coordenadas" é essa do where?

Comment: Existe essa função?

Comment: Ola não existe função, oque eu queria aqui e e fazer uma consulta se na coluna coordenadas existe estes dados 22.970981 -43.217496